# Cassandra dropped keyspaces still on HDD

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I noticed an increase in the number of open files on my cassandra cluster and went to check the health of it.  Nodetool status reported only 300gb in use per node of the 3TB each has allocated.

Shortly there after i began to see HEAP OOM errors showing up in the cassandra logs.

These nodes had been running for 3-4 months no issue, but had a series of test data populate and then dropped from them.

After checking the harddrives via the `df` command i was able to determine they were all between 90-100% filled in a jboded scenario.

edit: further investigation shows that the remaining files are in the 'snapshot' subfolder and the data subfolder itself has no db tables.

**My question** is, has anyone seen this?  Why did compaction not free these tombstones?  Is this a bug?

Comment: Seems like the appropriate response is after dropping a table to clear the snapshots if this was indeed on purpose.  this can be achieved by `nodetool -h localhost -p 7199 clearsnapshot`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snapshots occur over the lifetime of the cassandra cluster.  These snapshots are not captured in a `nodetool status` but still occupy space.  In this case the snapshots consuming all the space were created when a table was dropped.

To retrieve a list of current snapshots use the command `nodetool listsnapshots`

This feature can be disabled through editing `/etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh` and setting `auto_snapshot` to false.  Alternatively these snapshots can be purged via the command `nodetool clearsnapshot <name>`.

Answer (score 0):

Snapshots aren't tombstones - they are a backup of your data.

As Highstead says you can drop any unused snapshots via the clearsnapshot command.

You can disable the automatic snapshot facility via the cassandra.yaml

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html#reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__auto_snapshot

Answer (score 0):

Also check if you may have non-default true for [snapshot_before_compaction](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html#reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__snapshot_before_compaction)